# How to handle exceptions in F# when using sequence expressions?

Tags: f#

I am trying to write a F# function that reads a CSV file and returns its lines as a sequence of strings that can be further processed in a pipelined expression. The function should handle all exceptions that can arise when opening and reading a file. This is what I came up with so far:

```
// takes a filename and returns a sequence of strings
// returns empty sequence in case file could not be opened
let readFile (f : string) = 
  try 
    seq {
      use r = new StreamReader(f) // if this throws, exception is not caught below 
      while not r.EndOfStream do
        yield reader.ReadLine()   // same here 
    }
    with ex
        | ex when (ex :? Exception) -> 
            printfn "Exception: %s" ex.Message
            Seq.empty
```

The problem here is that the exceptions that could be thrown by `StreamReader()` and `ReadLine()` are not caught in the exception handler but instead are left uncaught and lead to program termination. Also, there seems to be no way of trying to catch exceptions inside the `seq {}` sequence expression. Right now I cannot think of any other way to design such a function than reading the whole file into an intermediate collection like a list or an array beforehand and then returning this collection as a sequence to the callers, thereby loosing all the benefits of lazy evaluation.

Has anybody got a better idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the exceptions are not caught by the try-with handler here is that the body of the `seq` is lazily executed. `readFile` returns the sequence without generating an exception, but then trying to execute that sequence generates an exception in the context where it is being used.

Since F# doesn't let you use try-with within a sequence expression, you have to be a bit creative here. You could use `Seq.unfold` to generate the sequence like so, for instance:

```
let readFile (f: string) =
    try
        new StreamReader(f)
        |> Seq.unfold
            (fun reader ->
                try
                    if not reader.EndOfStream then
                        Some(reader.ReadLine(), reader)
                    else
                        reader.Dispose()
                        None
                with ex ->
                    printfn "Exception while reading line: %O" ex
                    reader.Dispose()
                    None)
    with ex ->
        printfn "Exception while opening the file: %O" ex
        Seq.empty
```

Perhaps a less tricky approach would be to wrap `StreamReader.ReadLine` so that it doesn't throw exceptions. That way you can still use a `seq` expression and a `use` statement.

```
let readLine (reader: StreamReader) =
    try
        reader.ReadLine() |> Some
    with ex ->
        printfn "Exception while reading line: %O" ex
        None

let readFile2 (f: string) =
    try
        let r = new StreamReader(f)

        seq {
            use reader = r
            let mutable error = false

            while not error && not reader.EndOfStream do
                let nextLine = readLine reader
                if nextLine.IsSome then yield nextLine.Value else error <- true
        }
    with ex ->
        printfn "Exception while opening the file: %O" ex
        Seq.empty
```

Comment: accepted answer because it is more general, i.e. both versions could also be uses in a scenario where distinguishing between different exceptions (opening file, reading lines) is important

Answer (score 4):

```
let readFile (f : string) = 
    try File.ReadLines(f)
    with ex -> printfn "Exception: %s" ex.Message; Seq.empty
```

Comment: very nice and maybe even better for this special case of reading lines from a textfile in a pipeline-friendly manner